# uilabel gets deallocated prematurely in ARC

Tags: ios, uilabel, automatic-ref-counting, memory-management

I've been working on a project for several weeks, and recently implemented a singleton object to assist with saving data. After this was implemented, I've been having issues updating labels inside my main view controller.

For example, I'm trying to update the following labels:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *numDrinksLabel;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *BACLabel;
```

with the following code, which is inside a function that gets called on a button press:

```
BACLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", user.BAC];
numDrinksLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(%i)", user.numDrinks];
```

this code block gives me the runtime error:

```
-[__NSCFString setText:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1197ef40
```

However, the same code block called inside `viewDidLoad` or `viewDidAppear` is executed with no problems. Initially this suggested to me that there was a problem with my `@property` declaration, but I get the same error when I change `retain` to `strong`, and when I change to `weak`, the uilabel object is simply null, which is to be expected but nonetheless  very frustrating.

So the question is, why would the label objects become dealloced after the `viewDidAppear` function?

Any suggestions on how to fix this or further test for the root cause would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: IBOutlets should normally declared as weak, as the view they are contained in holds a strong pointer to them. That being said, your error is saying that you're sending setText to a string rather than a label. Are you sure this code is where the error is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your object which contains the iVars `numDrinksLabel` and `BACLabel` does no longer exist when you assign something to the text property of the `UILabel` objects.
Since this happens after you press a button, you have been in the main event loop before. In this loop, any autorelease object will be released if it is not retained by some object.
Thus it seems to me that the object that has your `UILabels` as iVars is an autorelease object, and it is not retained because you don't use setter methods like `self.BACLabel.text =` but simply assign methods as `BACLabel.text =`.
So try replacing your assignments like `BACLabel.text =` by setters like `self.BACLabel.text =`, as sixthcent said.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if the superview of these labels is also declared `strong`

Comment: Also, try accessing the labels as self.BACLabel instead of BACLabel.